# Where can I find the ways to share my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, flair

I've found out that I can use this to share my profile:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2571840/manolo-salsas" sl-processed="1">
<img width="208" height="58" title="profile for Manolo Salsas at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" alt="profile for Manolo Salsas at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers" src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/2571840.png?theme=dark">
</a>
```

Where can I find more information about this?

Comment: It is called *Flair*.

Comment: Exactly what information are you looking for? You've asked a very broad question...

Comment: From where did you find it?

Comment: I didn't know it was called *Flair*. Now it's clear at My profile -> Flair.

Comment: Also what did you put the feature request tag for? What are you requesting?

Comment: @Lix meta newbie - we all were new at some point. ;)

Comment: Flair is removed?

Comment: @MahyarMottaghiZadeh  no, it's under `profile/settings/Flair`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's called ***Flair*** and you can find it [**on your profile page**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2571840/manolo-salsas/flair)

[image]

Comment: Not anymore, I guess?

Comment: It is still in your Profile, but is apparently now under Settings -> Site Settings -> Flair.

Comment: @ascendants yeah, for me, path is : `stackoverflow.com/users/14343554/aayush-shah/flair`

Comment: This is the generic link for everyone to access the flair page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair